# Has Stack Exchange considered selling this website model for others' private internal use?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange

I work on a large IT project and we have ~50 developers. Our wiki is sub-standard and a lot of questions go unanswered. Often, I come to Stack Overflow and have to spend time asking a question in a very abstract form, so that I do not post company code on this site. So I wondered, wouldn't it be easier if I could use Stack Overflow in work, and ask my co-workers (who are allowed to see all the sensitive code).

Has Stack Exchange thought about selling this model to software devleopment companies? This sort of slick Q&A website would allow developers to ask questions full of confidential information, that could **remain on our company's servers** and not touch the outside world.

It would also (much more importantly) provide a way of documenting the project and providing new team members with easy access to a body of established information.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16054/is-the-stack-exchange-engine-available

Comment: See also SO clones, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/stack-exchange-clones

Comment: USAA purchased a license (or whatever it is that allows them to use it internally), so yeah.

Comment: Amusingly, the company I work for did indeed remodel their customer support forum a couple years ago to be basically a clone of SO (well, the important user-facing features of it, anyway), which they built from scratch internally. As a big fan of SO and its model, I'm not complaining - it's generated way more useful answers about our software than the old support forum did.

Comment: "Often, I come to Stack Overflow and have to spend time asking a question in a very abstract form, so that I do not post company code on this site." That isn't necessarily a bad thing. Sometimes, getting your head out of the specifics makes you see aspects of your problem you didn't before. Writing a SSCCE frequently helps you understand what's really happening and find the problem on your own. Bottom line: it makes you change your perspective, and that's often helpful.

Comment: See @Pekka웃's comment for a good list of alternative platforms. Many of them are free and open source. For the record, I've tried Question2Answer and found it to be excellent. It obviously doesn't have all the features of SO, but what it does do it does well.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

They will make a [private one for you they host](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/16054/178816), but it is expensive (they use top of the line hardware if you haven't noticed).

You could reproduce the entire aim of the site, hire developers, spend years working on developing a system similar to this site only to eventually realize that all your effort just led to a system which already existed to replace functionality that your business is already handling.

You will probably never be able to purchase or obtain a set of their source code, and even if you did implementing the infrastructure for the ["always caching"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/221414/178816), automated jquery producing, [sql execution plan storing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/224165/178816) behemoth would be very tricky without unicorns.

All in all, it is probably best to just make a nice, [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/) of your issue and post it here. Or, if your current wiki isn't quite up to snuff, make small improvements there.

tmd;dr; ([too much drivel, didn't read](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/258927/178816)) Unless your company is so large that it is publicly traded contracting a private exchange is probably too expensive; implementing your own would probably take too many resources; and the system in place seems to work good enough. I would just stick to your current process.

Comment: "*jquery producing sql*" - is that a typo or didn't I get the joke?

Comment: @Bergi - It was a slight jab at T4 templates for code generation, but the lack of a comma made it read wrong. Kind of like the sentence "I like to eat my pets and my family". ;) I edited it to hopefully make more sense